# Does there exist a database of formalized definitions and theorems based on NBG set heory?

Tags: formal-proof, formalization

Is there a library of formalized mathematical definitions and theorems similar to Lean's mathlib, but based on Von Neumann–Bernays–Gödel set theory and first order logic, rather than type theory? I am aware of the existence of the Mizar Mathematical Library, based on Tarski-Grothendieck set theory, however TG is not finitely axiomatizable unlike NBG.

There is also the TPTP library, which contains some problems based on the NBG axioms, but these seem to be directly about set theory. What I'm looking for is something that develops the basic notions of arithmetic, algebra, analysis, topology etc.

I'm mostly interested in the definitions and statements of theorems, not necessarily the formalized proofs. Also, it needn't be based on NBG, just some finitely axiomatizable set theory in first order logic.